# iTextPDF 5.5 : Why 2 times table created when used table.writeSelectedRows()?

Tags: itext

I want to add table middle of page after header.
Found method 'writeSelectedRows' which can be used to move table location on page.
But with this method, table is created 2 times, one at the start of the page, other at the specified location.

Please help in resolving this.

```
//Using iTextPDF 5.5.10

        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
//      table.setPaddingTop(250);
        table.setTotalWidth(100);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Some text here"));
//        cell.setFixedHeight(13);
        cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setColspan(1);
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.CYAN);
        table.addCell(cell);

        table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 50, 650, writer.getDirectContent());
        document.add(table);
        document.open();
```

This generates following output.
[image]

I want to add table at given location one time only and not at start of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table appears twice in your document because you add it twice! First you add it at the desired position:

```
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 50, 650, writer.getDirectContent());
```

And then you add it for automatic layout, putting it at the top of the page:

```
document.add(table);
```

If you only want it once, add it only once, i.e. remove one of those lines.